# Imparfait ou passé composé : « Si cet hôtel [être] longtemps un palace, il ne l'est plus » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subordonnées

Pourriez-vous me dire s'il faut employer le passé composé ou l'imparfait dans cette phrase :

> Si cet hôtel (être) longtemps un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.

Je dirais *était* parce qu'il s'agit d'une durée indéterminéee. (longtemps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J'utiliserais le passé composé puisque le fait rapporté est précis et achevé, l'imparfait sous-tend une action continue.

> Si cet hôtel a longtemps été un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord: comme je l'ai précisé, le fait d’être un palace est une action qui a duré dans le temps, donc imparfait.

Comment: @am304: L'action a, certes, duré mais elle est terminée donc, passé composé. Par ailleurs un imparfait dans la subordonnée implique un conditionnel dans la principale.

Comment: Comme on dit en anglais, "let's agree to disagree".

Comment: L'imparfait ne convient pas, difficile à expliquer, il heurte l'oreille. Le passé composé convient parfaitement, mais le passé simple me semble meilleur, même s'il est de moins en moins utilisé

Comment: Apres mure réflexion, vous avez raison, j'ai été un peu trop vite... Je ne peux malheureusement pas effacer ma réponse car elle a été acceptée, et je ne peux pas non plus changer mon vote -1, désolé!! Je vais changer ma réponse.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a pas d'autre possibilité que le passé composé  ou le passé simple dans le style littéraire ;

- Si cet hôtel a longtemps été un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.
- Si cet hôtel fut longtemps un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.

  Le passé composé (ou passé simple)  élimine la notion habituelle de condition qu'introduit « si » et l'interprétation de « si » change pour devenir la suivante, expliquée dans le TLFi ;

> (TLFi) [Si pose une rel. de type adversatif]
>   1. [L'énonciateur, tout en admettant la vérité de p, allant dans le sens d'une conclusion déterminée, avance un argument q qui contredit cette conclusion]
>
> - Dans l'ancienne société féodale, si le seigneur possédait de grands droits, il avait aussi de grandes charges.
> - Je paraîtrais plutôt plus jeune que mon âge. Je suis gros, c'est ce qui explique ton erreur; mais, si j'ai du ventre, je n'ai pas de rides.

« p » dans cette explication est « Si cet hôtel a longtemps été un palace ».

Si au contraire on utilise l'imparfait on obtient une simple condition, ce qui résulte en non-sens ;

-<s>Si cet hôtel était longtemps un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.</s>

Cependant on peut changer les temps et le sens reste le même sauf que le contexte est placé dans le passé ; encore une fois on trouve qu'il faut un temps des actions révolues, le plus-que parfait ;

- Si cet hôtel **avait** longtemps **été** un palace, il ne l’**était** vraiment plus.

Comment: @Toto Vous m'avez tous les deux convaincu avec LPH. Vous avez raison, j'ai été un peu trop vite :-( Je ne peux malheureusement pas effacer ma réponse car elle a été acceptée, je vais donc devoir la changer. Merci et encore désolé!!

Answer (score 2):

Comme d'autres l'ont dit, bien que le fait d’être un palace est une action qui a duré dans le temps, elle est maintenant finie. Il faut donc utiliser la passé composé et non l'imparfait comme je l'avais initialement suggéré:

> Si cet hôtel a longtemps été un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.

Une autre possibilité est l'utilisation du passé simple, qui est peut-être un peu plus littéraire que le passe composé:

> Si cet hôtel fut longtemps un palace, il ne l’est vraiment plus.

Comment: Justement: l'action est achevée, puisque l'hôtel n'est plus un palace, après l'avoir été. Le passé composé est donc correct. "Si cet hôtel a longtemps été un palace, il ne l'est vraiment plus."

Comment: @Greg oui l'action est achevée, mais elle a duré dans le temps, ce n’était pas une action ponctuelle: l’hôtel était un palace surement pendant de nombreuses années, il n'a pas été un palace pendant quelques minutes, et après c’était fini. Je persiste et signe: entre l'imparfait et le passé composé, je choisirais l'imparfait.

Comment: J'ai change ma réponse pour le passé composé, toutes mes excuses de vous avoir induit en erreur et merci aux autres utilisateurs de m'avoir corrigé!